# Microphone lowers input sound to zero randomly in 22.04

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone

I've recently installed Ubuntu and I am experiencing problems with my built-in USB camera microphone.

When I'm having a Teams meeting (in Teams for Linux or Teams in Chrome) it lowers the volume exactly at the moment when I start speaking.

This is why I have to keep AlsaMixer open and quickly turn the volume up when it gets down to zero:

[image: Alsa screenshot]

I believe that this is not how auto-adjust should work (by switching it to zero), and also there are no auto-adjust input sound options in Teams or Chrome so I suspect it could be something else.

Also is there an option for fixing the input level and protecting it from being overriding by other processes?